# Edit Workflow Infopath Form

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath

I have created a workflow which "collect data from a user" and "update list item column". So far so good, but there are 5 step which should be done one after another from different users.

The plan is to show in some WF Infopath Form tasks contents from previous steps. 
How can I handle this? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: May i know what type of solution you are expecting, whether you need to bring item details from last Wf process, or you need to use any Rules?

Comment: I want to bring some details from the last WF process to the new WF task form. Hope you understand what i want to do.